# Add column by mutate using nested ifelse conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column `source2` in my long format dataset, based on multiple conditions using `mutate` and `plyr`.

To get new values, I am looking for the number of factors in my group. If there is only one level, use this level. But, if there is combination of distance values, set this accordingly:

```
distance == "b20" & distance == "b5"  =>  "buffer",
distance == "PA" & distance == "b5")  =>  "pa_buff20",
distance == "PA" & distance == "b20") =>  "pa_buff500"
```

I think that nested `ifelse` statement should do this, but it seems my combination does not work. is it because I first check for the number of levels? 
(the first `ifelse` for the number of group is also the reason why I probably cannot simply use `case_when`).

My dummy dataset:

```
# how to find a year when a lag value overpass the certain threshold
df<- data.frame(year = c(1,1,2,1,5,5,10),
                distance = c("b20", "b5", "b20", "b20", "PA", "b5", "PA"),
                site     = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e"))


# Create new columns based on number of levels in `distance`
df %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(source = ifelse(n_distinct(distance) == 1,   # create source column based of number of factors
                       as.character(distance[1]), 'unclear')) %>% 
  mutate(source2 = ifelse(n_distinct(distance) == 1,   # create source column based of number of factors
                          as.character(distance[1]), 
                          ifelse(distance == "b20" & distance == "b5"), "buffer",
                          ifelse(distance == "PA" & distance == "b5"), "pa_buff20",
                          ifelse(distance == "PA" & distance == "b20"), "pa_buff500")) %>% 
  print()
```

I have and `Error in ifelse(n_distinct(distance) == 1, as.character(distance[1]),  : 
  unused arguments ("buffer", ifelse(distance == "PA" & distance == "b5"), "pa_buff20", ifelse(distance == "PA" & distance == "b20"), "pa_buff500")`

How to correct this `ifelse` statement?

Expected output:

```
   year distance site  source  source2
  <dbl> <fct>    <fct> <chr>   <chr> 
1     1 b20      a     unclear buffer
2     1 b5       a     unclear buffer
3     2 b20      b     b20     b20
4     1 b20      c     b20     b20
5     5 PA       d     unclear pa_buff20
6     5 b5       d     unclear pa_buff20
7    10 PA       e     PA      PA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of nested `ifelse` we can use `case_when` which is perfect for this case.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(distance = as.character(distance)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(source2 = case_when(all(c("b20", "b5") %in% distance) ~ "buffer", 
                             all(c("PA", "b5") %in% distance) ~ "pa_buff20",
                             all(c("PA", "b20") %in% distance) ~ "pa_buff500",
                             n_distinct(distance) == 1 ~ distance, 
                             TRUE ~ NA_character_))


#   year distance site  source2  
#  <dbl> <chr>    <fct> <chr>    
#1     1 b20      a     buffer   
#2     1 b5       a     buffer   
#3     2 b20      b     b20      
#4     1 b20      c     b20      
#5     5 PA       d     pa_buff20
#6     5 b5       d     pa_buff20
#7    10 PA       e     PA
```

As mentioned earlier `case_when` is an alternative to multiple nested `ifelse` statement where LHS is the condition we are checking and RHS is the value which we want to be returned. The conditions are evaluated sequentially. If none of the condition match by default `NA` is returned which is mentioned explicitly using `TRUE` condition here.

Comment: thank you very much, it seems working! Can you please add some more explanation? I am trying to understand `case_when` but I don't get the `TRUE` statememnt at the end? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when

Comment: @maycca added some explanation. `TRUE` statement is basically the value to be taken if none of the condition matches above, here the value is `NA_character_`.